# Scala shutwodn akka-htpp server with post method

Tags: scala, post, akka, akka-http

Don't understand why I can't off akka-http server.

Have the next code:

```
   path("api" / "system" / "shutdown") {
     logger.warning("shutting down insights application")
     appLifecycle.shutdown()
     complete(JsObject(Map("status" -> JsString("shutting_down"))))
   }
 }

def shutdown(): Unit                         = actor ! Shutdown
```

As a result, I got the next message -> `The requested resource could not be found inside chrome`
I also got next message inside terminal -> `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: java.io.StringReader@421ea4c0; line: 1, column: 1]`

Any ideas?

Comment: What is `appLifecycle`? What is `actor`? Please read how to create [mcve]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all I think you should add a `post` directive, then you should either do:

```
system.terminate()
```

or:

```
actor ! Kill // or PoisonPill
```